# Communication between Servlet & Applet fails when it was working

Tags: java, apache, servlets, applet

*I have an applet (where the user logins) & on pressing login button I send the login details to my servlet. In my applet, the function responsible for sending the login details to the servelt & receiving the servlet response object **FAILS**.*

**My problem is:** I dont know why my function sendObject( Object o ) fails & I dont know how to fix it. Could you help me understand what is wrong & why?

I am using Apache 7.0. I think that receiving the response (getting the input stream) from the servlet fails but I dont know why & logging in was working fine the other day so I know my WEB-INF folder is set up fine & the web.xml is fine.

My function (I document where the function fails):

```
public ArrayList <Object> sendObject( Object o )
{
    try
    {
        URL servletUrl = new URL( this.getCodeBase(), "Updater" ); // "http://localhost:8080/" );
        URLConnection conn = servletUrl.openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput( true );
        conn.setDoOutput( true );
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-java-serialized-object" );

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream( out );
        objOut.writeObject( o ); 
        objOut.flush(); 
        objOut.close();

        // receive result from servlet
        System.out.println( "Result from applet.getCodeBase()=" + this.getCodeBase() );
     // The following line is where I get the exception thrown
        InputStream instr = conn.getInputStream();              
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
        ArrayList <Object> result = (ArrayList <Object>) inputFromServlet.readObject();
        inputFromServlet.close();
        instr.close();

        System.out.println( "Contents of output is " );
        for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println( "" + result.get(i) );
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "In sendObject(): " + e );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( "In sendObject(): " + e );
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Java Console Output:**

> Result from applet.getCodeBase() = http://localhost:8080/Updater/
>   In sendObject(): java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/Updater/Updater

From the Apache log:

> 20/02/2011 11:15:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
>   20/02/2011 11:15:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
>   20/02/2011 11:15:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Marking servlet Updater as unavailable
>   20/02/2011 11:15:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Updater
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)
>       at UpdaterServlet.(UpdaterServlet.java:32)   // REFER BELOW TO SEE LINE 32 OF THIS FILE
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:799)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

localhost_access_log...:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:12 +1100] "GET /Updater/index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:15 +1100] "GET /Updater/UpdaterApplet.class HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:15 +1100] "GET /Updater/ContentTree.class HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:15 +1100] "GET /Updater/ContentMap.class HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:15 +1100] "GET /Updater/UpdaterApplet$1.class HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:15 +1100] "GET /Updater/SQLInterface.class HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:23 +1100] "GET /Updater/ObjSerializationInterface.class HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:11:15:23 +1100] "POST /Updater/Updater HTTP/1.1" 500 3117

This is the UpdaterServlet.java file (if you see above theres an error at line 32 of this file):

```
public class UpdaterServlet extends HttpServlet
{
// Class Variables:
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ArrayList <File> localDatabases;
private ArrayList <ArrayList <Object>> input;
private ArrayList <ArrayList <Object>> output;

// Class Methods:

public UpdaterServlet()
{
    getServletContext().log( "File open/created" ); // LINE 32
    localDatabases = new ArrayList <File>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `getServletContext()` returns `null`; are you also overriding the `init(ServletConfig)` method in the `UpdaterServlet`? If so, make sure to call `super.init(config)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually no, I dont overwrite the init() (nor the destroy, start or stop ones) should I be calling the super methods in these?

Comment: No, you don't *have* to override these methods but if you were overriding the `init(ServletConfig)`, you would likely want to call it on `super` as well. Not doing that is usually the reason for getting an null `ServletContext`.

On the other hand, Paulo is right as well- your base URL already includes the Updater context so concatenating Updater to it when creating your servlet URL is what adds the extra Updater to it. I'm not entirely convinced that that's the problem though since your do have an underlying NPE at line 32 which you've pointed out is the log method call on the ServletContext.

Answer (score 1):

This NPE means that the `ServletConfig` is not present (from where the `ServletContext` is to be returned). This is indeed not available in the **constructor** of the servlet. The servletcontainer sets it *after* construction of the servlet. You need to do the desired job in `init()` method instead.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    getServletContext().log( "File open/created" ); // LINE 32
    localDatabases = new ArrayList <File>();
    // ...
}
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, the stacktrace also hints that your servlet is in the default package. This will only work in very specific circumstances (certain Apache Tomcat versions in combination with certain JDK versions). I strongly recommend to put the servlet class in a package and alter the `web.xml` accordingly so that you aren't dependent on that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So, does your webserver know what to do on `/Updater/Updater`? It looks like not. Take a look at the error log, there should be more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted the error logs above. There are other error logs though, what log would you like me to post?

Comment: @Paulo Why is it returning http://localhost:8080/Updater/Updater & not  http://localhost:8080/Updater/? There is no path/folder  http://localhost:8080/Updater/Updater so I dont know if I need to create this or what to put in the path

Comment: Your codebase is `http://localhost:8080/Updater/` (since the applet is inside the index.html), and your applet is adding `Updater` to this, which gets you to the `http://localhost:8080/Updater/Updater` URL.  (I know about nothing about servlet configurations, so I can't help you there.)

Comment: He's using same name for context path and servlet path. This is indeed confusing, but the stacktrace is enough evidence that the servlet **is** called. So the URL is fine.